# Implement objective-c protocol in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

This question has been asked before, but never with my specific problem:

```
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogName;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<BlogParserDelegate> delegate; // This is my first problem
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *blogSocialNetworkUserNames; // This is my second problem
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogLogoImageLink;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogWebsite;
```

I don't know how to implement the two marked properties in Swift, I've tried a few things, and this was my last unsuccessful attempt:

```
@NSCopying var blogSocialNetworkUserNames : NSDictionary!
    var blogLogoImageLink : String!
```

The error I get is:

```
Type 'WordPressParser' does not conform to protocol 'BlogParserProtocol'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT added all the code:

protocol:

```
@protocol BlogParserProtocol <NSObject>

@required

#pragma mark Properties
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogName;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<BlogParserDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *blogSocialNetworkUserNames;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogLogoImageLink;
@property (readonly, copy, nonatomic) NSString *blogWebsite;

#pragma mark init methods
-(instancetype)initWithBlogName:(NSString*)blogName;

#pragma mark SFARSSParserProtocol methods

-(BOOL)isReachable;
-(void)readRSSAtURL:(NSString *)URL;
-(void)getCommentsFromArticleId:(NSString*)articleId;
-(void)addComment:(NSString*)comment
      toArticleId:(NSString*)articleId;

@end
```

Class that conforms to protocol:

```
class WordPressParser: NSObject, BlogParserProtocol {
    var blogName : String!
    var blogEmail : String!
    var delegate : AnyObject!
    var blogSocialNetworkUserNames : NSDictionary!
    var blogLogoImageLink : String!
    var blogWebsite : String!

    required init!(blogName: String!) {

    }

    func isReachable() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func readRSSAtURL(URL: String!) {

    }

    func getCommentsFromArticleId(articleId: String!) {

    }

    func addComment(comment: String!, toArticleId articleId: String!) {

    }
}
```

Error:

```
iPhone/ProjectName/WordPressParser.swift:11:1: Type 'WordPressParser' does not conform to protocol 'BlogParserProtocol'
```

Comment: Bad idea to have a strong `id <Protocol> delegate`.

Comment: @Mundi Not sure what you mean... why is it a bad idea, would changing it fix my problem?

Comment: It's complicated. In short it could lead to circular strong references and thus memory leaks. Use `assign`.  -- Also you did not mention what does not work. Please edit your question and be more explicit about what you expect and what the outcome is.

Comment: The problem is described there. I can't implement the marked properties in Swift (delegate & blogSocialNetworkUserNames). I've heard about the circular reference problem, I'll look more into it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: "Cannot implement" is not explicit. Please edit your question and tell us how you declare the `var`s and which errors you get.

Comment: Added the error. The way I'm declaring the bars is already in the question.

Comment: Sorry, but you put the wrong lines into your question.

Comment: What do you mean I put the wrong lines? Those two lines are the ones with the problem. I appreciate your help but please try to be constructive, don't just say I did the wrong thing. Please explain why you think that, otherwise we're both wasting our time.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error will disappear when you implement all required methods of protocol. Just write all required methods in your `WordPressParser` class and try to build application. It should be successful.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it doesn't work. The problem is that I don't know how to exactly implement those two protocol properties: (delegate & blogSocialNetworkUserNames). I'll paste the entire code so you can see it.